# Apache Camel route marshall Java Object to XML

Tags: apache-camel, marshalling, camel-ftp

I have java object with XML annotations

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ROOT")
public class Root {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "ATTR")
    private long site;

    @XmlElement(name = "LIST")
    List<MyObject> transaction;
}
```

and I have route to folder

```
from("firstPoint")
                .process(new RootToXMLConvertor())
                .to(FTP_FOLDER)
                .end();
```

I want to marshall my Root object (I have it in `exchange.getIn().getBody()`) to XML file and send to FTP_FOLDER.

Comment: Please add what version of camel you're using

Comment: I use camel 2.23.1

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JacksonXML Dataformat from Camel

```
JacksonXMLDataFormat formatPojo = new JacksonXMLDataFormat(Root.class);
from("firstPoint")
                .marshall(formatPojo)
                .to("file..")
                .to(FTP_FOLDER);
```

For doing this you'll need camel-jacksonxml, camel-ftp and the camel-file components.

Comment: Can I create file in .marshall(formatPojo).process(new FileCreator()).to(FTP_FOLDER)?

Comment: why creating a file in a processor when you can use a component for that? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I need to create dynamic filenames. And I have all information what i need in exchange.getIn().getBody(). If i use .to("file.."), how can i cnange file name dynamic?

Comment: By using a toD, which makes possible to change parameters dynamically on the uri endpoint.

Comment: Or you can set up CamelFileName header with value based on your body content and then Camel will use it for file and ftp producer